# spark Yarn mode how to get applicationId from spark-submit

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapr, spark-submit

When I submit spark job using spark-submit with master yarn and deploy-mode cluster, it doesn't print/return any applicationId and once job is completed I have to manually check MapReduce jobHistory or spark HistoryServer to get the job details.
 
My cluster is used by many users and it takes lot of time to spot my job  in jobHistory/HistoryServer.

is there any way to configure `spark-submit` to return the applicationId?

Note: I found many similar questions but their solutions retrieve applicationId within the driver code using `sparkcontext.applicationId` and in case of `master yarn and deploy-mode cluster` the driver also run as a part of mapreduce job, any logs or sysout printed to remote host log.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your note. The applicationId from the sparkcontext is the way to go

Comment: As my driver is launched on one of cluster node so how to send the applicationId from that node to client? is there any out of the box feature spark provides?

Comment: You can save applicationId to a file on hdfs.Many software use this way to keep processing id .

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it make sense to persists applicationId on HDFS and let client read it upon required. Another solution I implemented is notify user applicationId using email. @zhangtong Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the approaches that I used to achieve this:

1. Save the application Id to HDFS file. (Suggested by @zhangtong in comment).
2. Send an email alert with applictionId from driver.

Comment: A concise code snippet would really make it an answer